# portion of scrollable panel is always hidden

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a horizontally scrolling panel(2 rows layout) in which I push panels whenever store is loaded. If number of panels is more than 10-15 they go out of view and panel starts scrolling but it stops before actual end of content. If i pull it further I can see hidden content but as soon as I release it, it scrolls back and last few panels again goes beyond boundary.

Here is code of my view:

```
Ext.define('MyTabApp.view.CatalogList', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.cataloglist',
    config: {
        layout  : 'fit',
        id      : 'catalogList',
        style : 'background-color:#FFF',
        store   : null, // Placeholder for store
        hash    : null,
        items   : [{
            xtype   : 'toolbar',
            id      : 'seachbar',
            docked  : 'top',
            title   : 'Search results',
            items   : [{
                xtype   : 'button',
                text    : 'back',
                ui      : 'back'
            }, 
            {
                xtype   : 'button',
                text    : 'Filter',
            },
            {
                xtype   : 'button',
                text    : 'Sort',
                id      : 'sortBtn',
                right   : 0,
                style   : 'margin-top: 0.3em;'
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype       : 'panel',
            id          : 'searchPanel',
            layout      : 'hbox',
//          html        : 'search results',
            scrollable  : {
                direction       : 'horizontal',
                directionLock   : true
            }
        }]
    },
    innerTpl    : MyTabApp.app.getMulticolumnListTpl(),
    updateData  : function(records) {
        if(records.length != 0) {
            var innerTpl = this.innerTpl;
            var data = [];
            for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
                data[i] = records[i].getData();
                data[i].searchImage = Utils.updateImgResolution(records[i].getData().searchImage, "240_320");
            }
            var plist = [];
            while(data.length){
                plist.push({
                    xtype   : 'panel',
                    layout  : 'fit',
                    data    : data.splice(0,10),
                    tpl     : innerTpl
                });
            }
            Ext.getCmp('searchPanel').add(plist);
        }
        Ext.getCmp('searchPanel').setMinWidth(5000);
        /*
         * Since removeData destroys all listeners so we need to bind it again
         */
        this.bindTap();
    },
    removeData  : function() {
        Ext.getCmp('searchPanel').destroy();
        this.add({
            xtype       : 'panel',
            id          : 'searchPanel',
            layout      : 'hbox',
            scrollable  : {
                direction       : 'horizontal',
                directionLock   : true
            }
        });
        if(this.config.store != null){
            this.config.store.destroy();
        }
    },
    initialize : function() {
        this.bindTap();
        this.callParent();
    },
    bindTap : function() {
        this.down('#searchPanel').element.on({
            scope: this,
            tap: 'onSearchTap'
        });
    },
    onSearchTap : function(e) {
        this.fireEvent("searchTapCmd", e);
    }
});
```

Whenever new content is loaded store calls `updateData`.

Here is template:

```
getMulticolumnListTpl : function()
{
    return new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div isdraggable="false" class="products">',
        '<div isdraggable="false" class="row landscape">',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '{% if (xindex % 2 === 1) { %}',
                    '<div isdraggable="false" class="product" ref="{id}">',
                        '<span style="float:right;"><img isdraggable="false" src="resources/icons/wishlist_temp.png" class="wishlist-icon"></img></span>',
                        '<div isdraggable="false" class="image" style="background-image:url({searchImage});"><!----></div>',
                        '<div isdraggable="false" class="name">{styleName}</div>',
                        '<div isdraggable="false" class="price">Rs. {discountedPrice}</div>',
                    '</div>',
                '{% } %}',
            '</tpl>',
        '</div>',

        '<div isdraggable="false" class="row landscape">',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '{% if (xindex % 2 === 0) { %}',
                '<div isdraggable="false" class="product" ref="{id}">',
                    '<span style="float:right;"><img isdraggable="false" src="resources/icons/wishlist_temp.png" style="width:24px; height:24px; opacity:0.5;"></img></span>',
                    '<div isdraggable="false" class="image" style="background-image:url({searchImage});"><!--<span style="float:right;"><img isdraggable="false" src="resources/icons/wishlist_temp.png" class="wishlist-icon"></img></span>--></div>',
                    '<div isdraggable="false" class="name">{styleName}</div>',
                    '<div isdraggable="false" class="price">Rs. {discountedPrice}</div>',

                '</div>',
            '{% } %}',
        '</tpl>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>');
},
```

and here is CSS for this template:

```
.products .x-innerhtml{display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #ccc;border-width:0 1px 1px 0}
.products .row{display:table-row}
.products .row>*{display:table-cell}
.products .row:last-child .product{border-bottom:0}
.products .product{background-size:80%;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;border-width:0 1px 1px 0;border-style:solid;border-color:#ddd;text-align:center}
.products .product .image{height: 240px;width: 180px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center}
.products .product img{-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}
.products .product .name{width:100%;padding:20px 10px 5px 10px;color:black;font-size:16px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis; font-size: 60%}
.products .product .price{width:100%;font-size:12px;color:#d14747;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}
.products .landscape .product{width: 300px;padding: 5px;}
.products .landscape .product .image{margin-top:36px; margin: auto;}
.products .wishlist-icon {width:24px; height:24px; opacity:0.5;}
```

I have tried changing `minWidth` of searchPanel but that also did not work.

Comment: try using container instead of panel.

Comment: That did not help. I am expecting this to be some issue with template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While rendering HTML templates, sencha touch messes up the translate calculations and creates a viewport thats smaller than whats required to show all the items. This can be fixed by creating all the components that renders as part of the parent container as Sencha Touch components(`Panel`/`Component` instead of `div`s in tpl), there by doing away with the `tpl`. You can still use tpl inside those individual containers if you want.